# Automatically copy a cells colour to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

This is a very simple problem that I can't seem to find the solution. Basically I use 3 different cell styles (good,neutral and bad). What I simply want to do is I want the cell adjacent to the one I colour coded to be the same colour. For example cell O11 I selected it to be good (green colour), hence cell M11 should automatically change its cell style according to cell O11.

Any suggestions?

P.S O11 will be set manually (no conditional formatting)

Comment: is the cell color in O11 set by conditional formatting?

Comment: No i forgot to mention that. O11 will be set manually everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to create a variable to hold the cells color value and set that value back to another cell. Use the following example:

Sub Copy_Color()
    Dim iColor As Long
    Dim i as long

```
for i = 11 to 20
    iColor = worksheets("Sheet name").range("M" & i).Interior.Color
    worksheets("Sheet name").range("O" & i).Interior.Color = iColor
next
```

End Sub

Comment: Yes! This is what I wanted! One last thing...is there a way to run this automatically whenever I set the cell style to the cell? I don't want to click run everytime or use a shortcut key everytime I change the cell style.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to create a variable to hold the cells color value and set that value back to another cell. Use the following example:`To solve your problem you need to create a variable to hold the cells color value and set that value back to another cell. Use the following example:

To solve your problem you need to create a variable to hold the cells color value and set that value back to another cell. Use the following example:

```
Sub Copy_Color()

    Dim iColor As Long
    iColor = ActiveCell.Interior.Color
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = iColor
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay so now what if the cells O11 - O20 colour are to correspond to the cells M11 - M20. How would I tackle this?

Comment: You could use the following.`Sub Copy_Color()
    Dim iColor As Long
    Dim i as long

    for i = 11 to 20
        iColor = worksheets("Sheet name").range("M" & i).Interior.Color
        worksheets("Sheet name").range("O" & i).Interior.Color = iColor
    next
End Sub`

Comment: I implemented the code above but it gives me a runtime error saying "Runtime error 424 ...Object required"

Comment: Use the code below. I had a problem when posting the answer. I tried again the code and it didn't show the error you mentioned.